# What is the reason behind marking forbidden pages as 404?

Tags: discussion, 403-forbidden

This came to my mind after my previous question. Actually, most of the 404 pages I stumble into on SE are forbidden (403, eh?), not that they can't be found. Examples of such pages would be trying to access /admin despite not being a mod, or trying to access deleted chatroom, or somebody's inbox or profile editor, etc. Why do they throw 404s instead of 403s or something similar?

Comment: [Security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)

Comment: Isn't this question "primarily opinion based?" ;) You can't possible know **why** unless you ask every website designer why they designed that way.

Comment: @DavidPostill Well this question relates purely to StackExchange sites, so by asking here on meta.stackexchange nicael *is* asking the website designers why it was designed this way.

Comment: Well, isn't the reference a valid reason? @JonW

Comment: @JonW I missed that bit. Let wait and see an answer from one of the developers ... ;)

Comment: For the same reason on a site login form you don't specify which of password or username were incorrect, and just state "one or both" is wrong. Security through obscurity is usually a bad path to walk, but in this case it's a good idea as there is no weird setup, just a "not found" instead of "access denied". Also, for them, "admin" arguably *doesn't* exist.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**"What is the reason behind marking forbidden pages as 404?"**

[Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

See [Obscurity is a Valid Security Layer](https://danielmiessler.com/study/security-by-obscurity/) for nice explanation (as well as the citation below).

---

Source [When Should You Return 404 Instead of 403 HTTP Status Code?](http://lockmedown.com/when-should-you-return-404-instead-of-403-http-status-code/) by Max McCarty.

> When talking about web application security, one common denominator
>   that repeatedly comes up is the act of disclosing sensitive
>   application data.
>
> ...
>
> In my last post on Security Misconfiguration, part of the discussion
>   was on properly handling error messages to ensure we don’t expose
>   sensitive data to our users.  But it was obvious that in certain
>   circumstances we can inadvertently disclose information that a
>   malicious user could use to their advantage just by returning the real
>   HTTP status code.  **One of those situations is when the resource is
>   forbidden (403).**
>
> An authorized user has requested a forbidden resource in which they
>   receive a HTTP 403 forbidden response to the request is a common
>   scenario.  However, **by returning the applicable and valid 403, we
>   have also made it clear that the resource does exist.**  The
>   disclosure of the resource might only provide a piece of the profile
>   puzzle a malicious user was assembling or it might actually directly
>   provide the user opportunities.  For example, a valid case could be
>   that a 3rd party web resource (.axd) had a known security flaw and
>   could be taken advantage of through other side channels when knowing
>   the resource exists.
>
> **Though, security through obscurity is never in of itself reliable security, it can be and should be used as part of any security
>   in-depth approach.**  We can leverage this approach when we determine
>   that it would be better to not disclose the existence of a resource,
>   but return 404 instead of 403 HTTP status code.  Unfortunately, if you
>   have ever attempting to do so, you will have found it less than
>   possible and far from easy.  Maybe you’ve even given up on the
>   attempt.
>
> ...

Comment: When first starting in security, I think it's great to properly identify when "security through obscurity" is being used. However, once you get more comfortable in the field and you're confident that your system isn't RELIANT upon these techniques, it's okay to introduce some obscurity as more of a defense-in-depth mechanism. For example, ensure that your resource is actually secure and access is controlled. Afterwards, there's still something to be said about preventing attackers from even learning about the existence of said resource. The 404 over 403 is therefore allowed by RFC 2616.

Answer (score 16):

Both existing answers say that this is a valid use of security through obscurity. Unfortunately, both miss the point of the original post: anyone attacking SE can easily determine with high confidence that **all these 404s are in fact actually 403s** in the same way the OP did … or just by reading this or similar posts, which are public. It would be silly indeed to suppose that someone attacking a highly visible site like SE would fail to dig up all the information (public and otherwise) that they can. And supposing that the designers of malware will stoutly cling to some standards-compliant, fully-generic attack code that has no hacky customizations for particular targets would be madness.

Therefore, this cannot be a valid security policy. It means nothing at all; it's just pointless obfuscation for the sake of it, or perhaps carelessness in setting up conformant response codes. And since it *does* make any legitimate generic clients that are standards-compliant a little bit less aware of the true situation, it's a bad idea, just like using tables for layout.

**Breaking standards in a predictable, *publicly-documented* way to ensure security will only sacrifice standards-compliance to achieve no additional security at all.**

Comment: This is the right answer. The existence of moderator tools, etc. *is not a secret*, but in fact is well-documented on Meta.SE for anyone who knows how to read, and even users who can't read can get around it by using a screen reader. The security through obscurity principle applies to *truly secret* resources. If SE (for example) tracks private banking information and doesn't want us to know that it does so, then yeah, they should return 404 when someone requests https://meta.stackexchange.com/banking.

Answer (score 9):

This is an acceptable practice used by many major websites. For example, GitHub returns a 404 when trying to access a private repository that you don't have access to. Facebook will also return a 404 when attempting to access the profile of an individual that you aren't authorized to see. The intent is that you shouldn't be able to learn about the existence of a resource unless you have authorization to view it.

This doesn't break standards either. [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4) states that for a 403 Forbidden status code, "If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead."

Comment: The difference is that Github and FB do not publicly list all existing private repository or profile names, so 404 is a plausible lie (usually it's correct, and you can't tell which is which). SE does list valid, consistent admin URLs, so the lie is pointlessly blatant.

Answer (score 8):

Why not have a scenario? If you are a guard guarding something secret, would you say "Hey, it exists, but you can't get it!" or "Nope, dunno what that is" when someone wants it? Obviously the second! Same here. If you say the first, the person now knows the existence of the thing. The second does not let you know. So if we try to access something confidential about a user, giving 403 will give the existence of it away, and hackers know where to find it. For most of us, 404 means not there! So we don't know if it really exists or its just a lie to protect user data.